# "Content view not yet created" on orientation change with ontabreselected, setSelection(0) in listfragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-listfragment, android-tabs, android-orientation

With Android 4.2, I'm using actionBar tabs to switch betwween list fragments with cursorloaders and sqlite, and all works fine.  I use the ontabreselected callback to move back to the top of the list with setSelection(0), which works, but crashes after a screen rotation (orientation change).  For example if I scroll down in the list at a specific position and rotate the screen, the fragment is recreated at the same position as desired, but if I reselect the tab to bring to the top with setSelection(0), it crashes with "Content view not yet created", as if the new recreated view is detached from the main activity.

My main activity implements ActionBar.TabListener

```
public class RestonetActivity extends Activity implements ListItemSelectListener,     ActionBar.TabListener{


private boolean useLogo = false;
private boolean showHomeUp = true;

private int tab_pos;

ListeFragment listeFrg = new ListeFragment();
AlphaListeFragment alphaFrg = new AlphaListeFragment();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);



     final ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
     ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(useLogo);
     ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
     ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
 ab.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
     tab_pos = savedInstanceState.getInt("tabState");
     ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_recente).setTabListener(this),0,false);
     ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_alpha).setTabListener(this),1,false);
     ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_fortes).setTabListener(this),2,false);
     ab.setSelectedNavigationItem(tab_pos);

    } else {
     ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_recente).setTabListener(new    TabListener<ListeFragment>(this,"recente",ListeFragment.class)));
ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_recente).setTabListener(this),0,true);
ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_alpha).setTabListener(this),1,false);
ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_fortes).setTabListener(this),2,false);
}
}

public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
     int position = tab.getPosition();
     Log.e ("ontabreselected", "pos= "+position);
      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();


      // position cursor at top of list if user retaps a tab
      switch (position) {
    case 0:
         if (null ==  fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("RECENT")) {

           ft.replace(R.id.listeFragment, listeFrg, "RECENT");
         }
           else{

         listeFrg.setSelection(0);
         }  
            break;
    case 1: 
         if (null == fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ALPHA")) {

             ft.replace(R.id.listeFragment, alphaFrg, "ALPHA");
         } else {    

             alphaFrg.setSelection(0);

         }
         break;
    case 2:
         break;

      }    

}
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    int position = tab.getPosition();

  int loaderID = 0;

  String fragmentTag;

  switch (position) {
case 0:

     loaderID=RESTO_RECENT_LOADER;

     if (null == fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("RECENT")) {
            ft.replace(R.id.listeFragment, listeFrg, "RECENT");
         }
         break;
case 1: 
    loaderID=RESTO_ALPHA_LOADER;
     if (null == fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ALPHA")) {
           ft.replace(R.id.listeFragment, alphaFrg, "ALPHA");
     }
     break;

  }    
  }
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {


}
```

Here is the listfragment code ( I omitted the second fragment as it is essentially identical)

```
public class ListeFragment extends ListFragment implements  LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>  {
private ListItemSelectListener listeSelectListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Log.e ("onAttach", "ListeFragment Attached ");

    try {
        listeSelectListener = (ListItemSelectListener) activity;

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " doit implementer ListItemSelectListener");
    }
}



@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    listeSelectListener.onItemSelected(position, id);

}


private static final int RESTO_RECENT_LOADER = 0x01;
private static final int RESTO_ALPHA_LOADER = 0x02;
private static final int RESTO_HIGH_LOADER = 0x03;
private static final int RESTO_SEARCH_LOADER = 0x04;


private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

public void afficheList(int loader_id, String query) {

    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    mBundle.putString("search_query", query);
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(loader_id, mBundle, this);
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] uiBindFrom = { RestoDatabase.COL_ETAB, RestoDatabase.COL_MONTANT };
    int[] uiBindTo = { R.id.TextView01, R.id.Montant };
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(), R.layout.row,
            null, uiBindFrom, uiBindTo,
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

@Override
public void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
// call initLoader on Resume avoids a bug which calls onLoadFinished twice

LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();

lm.initLoader(RESTO_RECENT_LOADER, null, this);

}


public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
      String[] projection = { RestoDatabase.ID, RestoDatabase.COL_ETAB, RestoDatabase.COL_MONTANT };
    switch (id){
        case RESTO_RECENT_LOADER:

            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    RestoProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, date_infraction DESC");

        case RESTO_ALPHA_LOADER:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    RestoProvider.CONTENT_URI_GROUPBY, projection, null, null,"etablissement ASC");



        default: return null;

    }
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);

}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
 }
```

Finally, here is the logcat, where line 307 in untabreselected is  `listeFrg.setSelection(0);`:

> 04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:386)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.app.ListFragment.setSelection(ListFragment.java:256)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at ca.usimage.resto.RestonetActivity.onTabReselected(RestonetActivity.java:307)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:560)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1067)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView.onItemClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:355)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup$1.onItemClick(Spinner.java:922)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   04-25 21:36:08.411: E/AndroidRuntime(23013):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, I'm not sure I fully understand why, but it works.  It involves revising the ontabreselected by casting the fragment object in order to call setSelection(0) as follows:

```
 public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
 int position = tab.getPosition();

  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();


  // position cursor at top of list if user retaps a tab
  switch (position) {
  case 0:
     if (null ==  fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("RECENT")) {

       ft.replace(R.id.listeFragment, listeFrg, "RECENT");
     }
       else{
       ListeFragment listeFrg = (ListeFragment)
       getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("RECENT");
       listeFrg.setSelection(0);

     }  
        break;
   case 1: 
     if (null == fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ALPHA")) {

         ft.replace(R.id.listeFragment, alphaFrg, "ALPHA");
     } else {    
     AlphaListeFragment alphaFrg = (AlphaListeFragment)
      getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ALPHA");
             alphaFrg.setSelection(0);

     }
     break;
    case 2:
     break;

  }    

}
```